# How to hide horizontal scroll indicator for ios in nativescript angular

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, radlistview

Hi I am developing application for iOS and Android using NativeScript-Angular. I have created horizontal `ListView` using `RadListView` plugin. Everything works fine, but the scroll indicator does not hide in iOS.

In Android the scroll indicator was hidden. How can I fix this issue in iOS?

My Html file:

```
 <RadListView row="0" selectionBehavior="Press" (itemSelected)="onItemSelected($event)"  #menurad class="m-t-10" row="0" height="50"  [items]="allMenuList">
                <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-themenu="item" let-i="index">
                        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" (tap)="menuClick(i)" >
                                <Label class="Selected" [text]="themenu.menuName" ></Label>
                                <Label width="20"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                </ng-template>
                <ListViewLinearLayout tkListViewLayout scrollDirection="Horizontal"></ListViewLinearLayout>
        </RadListView>
```

Comment: Since you have tagged this with `RadListView`, can you confirm which item layout you are using? A sample code could give even more clarity on what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: ok i will give you  my code.

Comment: Any solution? @ Manoj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for RadListView

```
onLoaded(event) {
    const listView = event.object;
    if (listView.ios) {
        listView.ios.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;

        // In case of vertical scrollbars uncomment the line below 
        // listView.ios.collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=qi4Ndf)

Answer (score 3):

iOS:
myListView.ios.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;

android:
myListView.android.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

Above code worked for me, for hiding Vertical scroll.
You can try the same for HorizontalScrollIndicator ...